Dirichlet series with $ f(1-s) = f(s) $ or a proven critical line $\Re(s)=1/2$?
Context
I read this :

This paper has been withdrawn by Farid Kenas
[Submitted on 8 Mar 2024 (v1), last revised 25 Aug 2024 (this version, v2)]
Attempting to Prove the Riemann Hypothesis through the Reflection Formula
Farid Kenas
The Riemann Hypothesis, originally proposed by the eminent mathematician Bernard Riemann in 1859, remains one of the most profound challenges in number theory. It posits that all non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ are concentrated precisely along the critical line where the real part equals 1/2. In this paper, our aim is to present an attempt to prove this conjecture. Our approach relies on the use of the reflection formula. By applying this tool with precision and insight, we can conclusively establish that $\xi(s)^2$ (Riemann's $\xi$-function) is valid only when $\Re(s)=1/2$. As a direct consequence of this determination, we can assert that every zero of both $\xi(s)^2$ and $\xi(s)$ has a real part equal to $1/2$. This, in turn, leads us to the tentative conclusion that the real part of all non-trivial zeros of the zeta function is consistently $1/2$.


Comments: An expert from the Annals of Mathematics confirmed that proving the Riemann Hypothesis using only the functional equation is not feasible. The expert referenced H. Davenport and H. Heilbronn's 1936 paper, "On the Zeros of Certain Dirichlet Series," which shows that functions can be constructed that meet the properties used in this paper but do not satisfy the Riemann Hypothesis.

This appeared this year $2024$ on arxiv and version 2 has been withdrawn (see here)
Now of course many functions satisfy similar reflection formulas , such as $\sin(x-1/2)$ or the dilogarithm reflection formula.
But I do not know Dirichlet series that do apart from those occoring in the GRH type conjectures and the Tau Dirichlet series (Ramanujan 's analogue of the RH for the Tau Dirichlet series/Ramanujan L-function (see here)).
Although Raman. L zeros are not at $\Re(s) = 1/2$.
Question(s)
So I was wondering: What are those other Dirichlet series that either have a proven reflection formula around $\Re(s) = 1/2$ or maybe even all their non-real zero's proven at $\Re(s)=1/2$ ?
Especially those of the paper?
And are those of the form
$$\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{(a_n)^s} \quad\text{ or }\quad \sum \frac{1}{(b_n)^s}$$
for strictly increasing sequences of positive integers $a_n$ or $b_n$?

The Riemann xi-function $$\xi (s)=\pi^{-\frac{s}{2}}, (s-1), \Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}+1\right), \zeta (s)=\pi^{-\frac{s}{2}}, (s-1), \Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2}+1\right) \sum {n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^s},,\quad\Re(s)>1$$ has an analytic continuation which obeys the functional equation $\xi (s)=\xi (1-s)$. I'm not aware of a non-trivial Dirichlet series of the form $$f(s)=\sum\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s}$$ that has an analytic continuation which obeys the functional equation $f(s)=f(1-s)$.

@Steven well for instance the reflection carries over to the derivatives. But perhaps you consider that as trivial :
https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.4

@StevenClark also this here contains a more general reflection formula for Dirichlet series :
https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.15

The Riemann $\xi(s)$ is not represented by Dirichlet series of the form $\xi(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s}$. Also, the more general reflection formula for Dirichlet L-functions (which are a specific type of Dirichlet series) is not of the form $L(s,\chi)=L(1-s,\chi)$. By trivial, I was referring to the cases $a_n=0$ and $a_n=\left{\begin{array}{cc}
1 & n=1 \
0 & n>1 \
\end{array}\right.$ where $f(s)=0$ and $f(s)=1$ obey the functional equation $f(s)=f(1-s)$.

@StevenClark thanks for clarification. Ofcourse the Riemann zeta function does have a reflection formula via the $\xi$, it is just not $f(s) = f(1-s)$.
Notice i did just say reflection formula in the question and I did not say that $f$ itself is a Dirichlet series. Maybe the title gave the impression that $f$ is a dirichlet series. $f$ is merely related to a Dirichlet series, just like $\xi$. I think this is in the same spirit or intention of the reference the expert gave.

The simple example that shows that one cannot prove RH from the functional equation only is the famous Davenport Heilbronn function (it's a linear combination of Dirichlet $L$ functions in modulus $5$ which satisfies a similar functional equation as zeta and the corresponding symmetry around $1/2$ when completed by gamma factors and the like; it is a general theorem (proven by Bagchi I think in full generality) that any non trivial - involving at least two distinct characters - linear combination of Dirichlet $L$ functions at a given modulus has zeroes with real part dense in $[1/2,1]$

As for RH analogues, it is a theorem of Helson that if $f_{\chi}(s)=\sum \chi(n)/n^s$ where $\chi$ lives in the compact topological group of (bounded) characters on the positive rationals - equivalently $\chi(p)$ is an arbitrary modulus $1$ number for any prime $p$ and then extension by multiplicativity to all positive integers with of course $\chi(1)=1$, group that has Haar measure being compact, then $f_{\chi}$ (which has an Euler product so doesn't vanish for $\Re s>1$ extends to a non vanishing analytic function up to $1/2$ for almost every character $\chi$ (wr Haar measure)

@Conrad do you have a reference for that ? So you are saying that the halfplane $Re(s) > 1/2$ does not have zero's for these type of functions ?

Unfortunately the result is just probabilistic of the almost everywhere in the Haar measure type and the proof is essentially a clever application of Fubini theorem (the treatise on Dirichlet series by McCarthy has it for example); so while the usual zeta is in this class when the character is trivial (identically one here) we cannot really say anything about a specific character and its function
